# Injected Web3 is not working in Browser-Solidity

Tags: remix, metamask

I am  using Metamask for ethereum testnet. And when i deploy my contract it run in my memory. And when I select the Injected Web3. It is not selected. Now what to do??

Please help me.

Comment: Here is the link of browser-solidity  [link](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.10+commit.f0d539ae.js).

Comment: I had the same problem as you Anurag Verma and fixed it by updating my MetaMask plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same solution, and when I have update MetaMask it works fine (web3 injected seen in the console).

To update MetaMask:

1/Click right button in MetaMask.

2/Manage extensions.

3/Click on Developer Mode.

4/update extension.

5/Enjoy ! ;)

Comment: you made my day 

Comment: I am using Chrome. At step 3), I don't see Developer Mode to check

Answer (score 1):

[image: developer mode on]

Developer mode is on the top right corner of the browser
Then refresh the browser before trying "Injected Web3" option again.

Answer (score 0):

In version 3.5.1, MetaMask refined the logic of what pages it would inject web3 in, checking for a valid html `doctype` header, to prevent injecting metamask logic into random XML pages.

Browser-solidity does not use a valid html `doctype` header.

I submitted [a patch to browser-solidity for this](https://github.com/ethereum/browser-solidity/pull/492), but we've also patched MetaMask to be more permissive, and [in MetaMask version 3.5.2](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-plugin/releases/tag/v3.5.2) browser solidity should work again.

Answer (score -1):

Injected Web3 is a feature in Browser-Solidity that allows the Solidity compiler to interact with a Web3-enabled browser. If you are experiencing issues with Injected Web3 not working in Browser-Solidity, here are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot the issue:

Make sure you have a Web3-enabled browser: Injected Web3 requires a browser with a Web3 provider, such as MetaMask or Mist. If you don't have a Web3-enabled browser, you won't be able to use Injected Web3 in Browser-Solidity.

Check that your Web3 provider is properly configured: If you have a Web3-enabled browser, make sure that your Web3 provider is properly configured and connected to a network. For example, if you are using MetaMask, make sure that you are connected to the network you want to interact with.

Try reloading the page: Sometimes Injected Web3 can fail to load properly. Try reloading the page to see if that resolves the issue.

Clear your browser cache and cookies: Clearing your browser cache and cookies can sometimes help resolve issues with Injected Web3.

Try using a different browser or computer: If the issue persists, try using a different browser or computer to see if the issue is specific to your current setup.

If none of these steps resolve the issue, it may be a more complex issue and you may need to seek further assistance from the Browser-Solidity community or a Solidity developer.

Comment: Welcome but plagiarizing ChatGPT isn't allowed here.